# Handle bower component image url with grunt

Tags: css, gruntjs, datatables

I am currently using datatables to create graphs.  The problem I have is that after I run grunt on my production server the css url references to (../images/photo.png) while the image is actually in (../assets/images/photo.png).

Is there anyway to make the update in grunt? I cannot update the css as datatables will not work locally anymore.

Thanks

Comment: is this for your grunt watch task? Is this just a different server or branch/code base as well?

Comment: Yes it is for the grunt watch task. It's just on a different server. Same code base.

Comment: can you post your gruntfile please?